# How kernel serial driver request user-mode application to read data?

Tags: windows, serial-port, kernel, driver, virtual

I am trying to develop kernel serial port driver for windows with asynchronous communication. I know I have to define IRPs calls for read/write etc. Writing data from user-mode app to driver is simple - just call proper IRP and you are mostly done. If it goes about reading data from serial - I am stuck. What is the mechanics of reading data from serial? I can't imagine that user-mode application is constantly requesting read IRP (waste of resources if you don't have any data to be transferred from driver to app). I thought that driver might rise a flag or something similar that have a data to be transferred. Please, help me understand how it works or how it is done in windows kernel.

Regards,
Luk

Answer (score 0):

User-mode application sends read request which is pending until data is ready. When data is transferred application sends next read request. 
[Link to answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/a8e7ac68-e87f-497e-855a-5e3cc6aacffa/serial-async-io-how-driver-request-from-app-to-read-data?forum=wdk#a8e7ac68-e87f-497e-855a-5e3cc6aacffa)